# Form valdiation fails

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Symfony 2, Following Code:

```
namespace frontend\mainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;

class ContactForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('subject', 'text');
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('message', 'textarea');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'name' => new Length(array("min" => 5)),
            'email' => new Email(
                array('message' => 'Invalid email address')
            ),
            'message' => new Length(array("min" => 5))
        ));

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'constraints' => $collectionConstraint
        ));
    }
}
```

DefaultController.php

```
    public function contactAction(Request $request)
{


  $form = $this->createForm(new ContactForm());  
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action, such as saving the task to the database
    break;
        //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
    }
}
return $this->render('frontendmainBundle:Default:contact.html.php', array(
    'form' => $form->createView()
));
}
```

contact.html.php

```
<form action="contact" method="post" <?php echo $view['form']->enctype($form) ?> >
    <?php echo $view['form']->widget($form) ?>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit the form, with subject, email, and message ('test', 'test@test.com', 'message text'), following error is coming up.

This field is missing.
Subject
This field was not expected. (I guess it is the email box)

I do have actually an error message in my code ('Invalid email address') This is not working too. Why?

Comment: How do you render your form in your template?

Comment: return $this->render('frontendmainBundle:Default:contact.html.php', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));

Why?

Comment: I mean how does your contact.html.php look like? can you post some code?

Comment: Ah, okay, I updated my code. Hope it helps

Comment: in `setDefaultOptions` you have a constraint for `name`, is it meant to be for `subject`?

Comment: Sorry, spelling mistake! THANKS!!!

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `setDefaultOptions` you have a constraint for **name** instead of **subject**